# Ember accessing a different controller from a route

Tags: ember.js

I want to access the applicationController from a different route (issue), inside `afterModel`.

The main goal is to change the background of the application once the promise model is resolved.

This is my `issue.js` :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  needs: ['application'],
  model: function(params) {
    [... some code ...]
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    model.issue.then(function(resolvedIssue) {

      // I'm looking to access the controller here
      var theOtherController = this.get('controllers.application');

      return resolvedIssue;
    });

  }

});
```

I've tried several combinations, without success.
When I try to log stuff in the console, I get a try/catch error message.

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of errors in your code. First, you do not have the scope of `issue` route in `model.issue.then(...)`, therefore `get('controller')` cannot work. Second of all, the `needs` statement is only valid for controllers, not routes.

You should send action in your `issue` route and catch it in `application` route using ember bubbling actions.

All actions that are send are bubbled up through routes up to `application` route. If `application` route does not handle this action, the error raises. Take a look at this code that should be in your `issue` route:

```
afterModel: function(model, transition) {
  var _this = this;
  model.issue.then(function(issue) {
    _this.send('changeLayout', issue.get('image'));
  });
}
```

And in your application route you can catch that action and e.g. execute some method on application controller:

```
toggleLayout: function(desiredImage) {
   // time to actually change the image here
   console.log("let's display " + desiredImage);
}
```

`application` route :

```
actions: {
  changeLayout: function(desiredImage) {
    this.get("controller").toggleLayout(desiredImage);
    return false; // make sure to stop bubbling up!
  }
}
```

It's way better than using any kind of `needs` as it fully covers convention of data-down-action-up.